# why setinterval slows down the website

Tags: php, jquery

I am using this simple function  but it much skows down the web site depending on the time the webpage has been opened.when user refresh  or goes to another page,it takes much time to refresh.

I am basically fecthing the user new posts.so time must keep running.

If i dont use this function then webpage loads quickly.Although this is a simple function
Plz help or suggest any alternarive approach.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setInterval( "timer();", 1000 );
});

function timer(){
    $.post('sendchat2.php', {option:'timer',id= $('#timer').val()}, function(data) {
        $('#timer').html(data);

    })
}
```

Comment: This has to do with the browser you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: "Although this is a simple function". We dont know if `data` contains a 10mb html file. You need to post some more relevant code.

Comment: Each second you are making a POST request to server. Your server have just the time to handle (respond)(or not) and is already sollicited again. You should rethink about your method.

Comment: @AugustoMen I have tested on both chrome and mozila

Comment: It is not a good way use setInterval and post a php file to get updates in every second. I suggest to use comet/long polling methods.

Comment: To debug this, if you open the Chrome develop bar then you can see how long each HTTP request is taking. Hit F12 and select the network tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
$(function () {

    var $timer = $ ( '#timer' );

    (function timeout () {
        $.post( 'sendchat2.php', { option: 'timer', id = $timer.val() }, function ( data ) {
            $timer.html( data );
            setTimeout( timeout, 1000 );  
        });            
    }());

});
```

So, you initiate the Ajax-request, wait for the response, inject it into the DOM, and only *then* initiate a one second timeout which repeats the whole process.

---

The general pattern:

```
(function f () {

    async(function () {

        // do work here

        setTimeout( f, delay );

    });

}());
```

So, the function `f` executes some asynchronous operation (e.g. Ajax request). The callback function of that operation performs some work (e.g. put Ajax response into DOM), and at the end it sets up a timer which invokes the `f` function after a given delay.

Comment: You should probably explain why that is a better approach? At a guess I would say adding the timeout to the response callback will mean that if the server takes a while to respond, then it at least doesn't get bombarded with new requests in the meantime.

Comment: @Sime I am basically fecthing the user new posts.so time must keep running.

Comment: @CutyPie The Ajax request can take anywhere from 20 milliseconds, to 30 seconds. You *cannnot* assume that it will take less than 1 second, and therefore you *cannot* do it with `setInterval`. If your server is alive and kicking, my code won't make your updates any slower. Btw, consider alternative solutions like WebSocket, or other techniques to have a persistent connection - doing Ajax requests every second does not scale well (if you have many visitors).

Comment: @PaulS I've provided an explanation in my answer. The idea is to have a one second timeout between a response and a subsequent request, instead of between two adjacent requests. (If it took one second for the response to arrive, there is no point of doing a new request immediately, since the response is brand new.)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Did you edit that, or did it just miss it at first?

Comment: @PaulS Ah, you were referring to that. In my original post, I accidentally left the `setTimout` outside of the success callback, but I fixed the code immediately.

Comment: @PaulS Ah, you were referring to the text below the code. Yes, that was edited later. I post code as soon as possible, and then add an explanation subsequently. `:)`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas You have wrapped the answer in two  function  or so.Plz do a little explanation about this code formate.Or reformate the answer in easy coding style like my question code formate.I am newly learning  JQ.plz never mind

Comment: @CutyPie The outer wrapper - `$(function () { ... });` is a shorthand for the document ready handler (`$(document).ready(function() { ... });`. The inner wrapper is the `timeout` function - this is the function that is invoked repeatedly. Notice how this function is also invoked immediately via `()`. This is not a simple pattern, so you may need to learn more about JavaScript, concretely about immediately invoked functions, and named function expressions.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Thanks for response.I overviewed these patterens by googling.but did not understand enough to implement.Could you plz render your answer into simple pattern.It will be much helpful for me,for comparison between these  two patterns as well as  instant solution.Thanks once again.

Comment: @CutyPie I have provided some explanation in my comment above. Did you understand what I said there? Could you specify what exactly confuses you in my code?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I am clear with the  first ready function.How will I convert second function to simple pattern.I have much code in my website as  a simple patteren.SO it is not much adviseable to reformate whole simple code into this type of comlex pattern now.It will create much confusion.I am just asking simple pattern of second function.Thanks

Comment: @CutyPie The second function is a pattern, and it cannot be simplified. I've added a generalized version of this pattern.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I try to impliment this patteren.but finding difficult plz review    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550216/why-this-mmediately-invoked-functions-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

The slowdown is not because of the `setInterval()`, you are calling that function "timer" every 1 second with setInterval, that should slow the page down only 1000 (1 second).

The problem is in the `$.post()`, which is an Ajax request, what that exactly do is, send some information to the script (php), php then processes the information resulting in some output, then this output is sent again to the first page, and the $.post() writes this information in your $('#timer') element.

So probably the slowdown is because of :

- The php script is where the delay is being generated
- The data returned from sendchat2.php is very big, therefore delaying the pageload.

Also, sending an ajax request every second is not very healthy, the php script could be being overloaded. You might want to google for push methods or polling methods to develop the chat correctly

Answer (score 0):

variable_of_response.open(method,url,**FALSE**)

i have the same problem ...but when i change the boolen value to false...that mean i didnot need data first before rendring my request...so its go well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).