# Why this mmediately invoked functions is not working properly

Tags: php, javascript

I am using immediately invoked functions pattern, but this is not passing the id

1.When the user clicks on $user, id is passed and the chat window appears

```
echo "<div class='boxbottom'><a href='#' onclick=chat_com_one($id);> >$user</a><br></div>";
```

2.Function chatcom_load_one keep checking, if there is any message from the id passed to chatcom_load_one function.

But the problem is that onclick function do passes the id but immediately invoked function did not pass the id to the post function.

Also sending the message is slow?

Please help or suggest any alternate approach, I think error is in the chat_load_one pattern.

```
function chat_com_one(id) {

    $('#chatcom').show('fast');
    (function chatcom_load_one(id) {
        $.post('sendchat2.php', {
            option: 'chatcom_load_one',
            tocom: id
        }, function (data) {
            $('#chatcom #commid #commidwin').html(data);
            setTimeout(chatcom_load_one(id), 1000);
        });
    }());
    $('#chatcom_send').click(function () {
        var text = document.getElementById('chatcom_text').value;
        $.post('sendchat2.php', {
            option: 'chat_com_send_one',
            text: text,
            tocom: id
        }, f
        function (data) {
            document.getElementById('chatcom_text').value = '';
        });
    });
}
```

send function on my server

```
    if($_REQUEST['option']=='chat_com_send_one'){
    $session=new $session;
    $text=mysqli_real_escape_string($db3->connection,$_POST['text']);
    $tocom=mysqli_real_escape_string($db3->connection,$_POST['tocom']);
    $sql=mysqli_query($db3->connection,"INSERT INTO chat_com(fro,tocom,mesg,time) VALUES ('$session->userid','$tocom','$text',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
}
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error at the last `$.post`: `f       function`.

Comment: @tjameson How can i remove this error<i am newly learning jquery complex pattern .plz suggest any answer about this.thanks

Comment: I made a series of fixes in my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I notice two problems:

- You have a syntax error in the parameter list to `$.post`
- You probably don't want to do this: `setTimeout(chatcom_load_one(id), 1000);`

Here's an updated version of your code with these errors fixed:

```
function chat_com_one(id) {

    $('#chatcom').show('fast');
    (function chatcom_load_one(id) {
        $.post('sendchat2.php', {
            option: 'chatcom_load_one',
            tocom: id
        }, function (data) {
            $('#chatcom #commid #commidwin').html(data);
            setTimeout(function () {
                chatcom_load_one(id);
            }, 1000);
        });
    }());

    $('#chatcom_send').click(function () {
        var text = document.getElementById('chatcom_text').value;
        $.post('sendchat2.php', {
            option: 'chat_com_send_one',
            text: text,
            tocom: id
        },
        function (data) {
            document.getElementById('chatcom_text').value = '';
        });
    });
}
```

Also, since you're using jQuery, you can simplify `document.getElementById...`. Another updated version (with some more changes to make it more readable):

```
function chat_com_one(id) {
    $('#chatcom').show('fast');

    (function chatcom_load_one(id) {
        $.post('sendchat2.php', {
            option: 'chatcom_load_one',
            tocom: id
        }, function (data) {
            $('#commidwin').html(data);
            setTimeout(function () {
                chatcom_load_one(id);
            }, 1000);
        });
    }(id));

    $('#chatcom_send').click(function () {
        var text = $('#chatcom_text').val();
        $.post('sendchat2.php', {
            option: 'chat_com_send_one',
            text: text,
            tocom: id
        },
        function (data) {
            $('#chatcom_text').val('');
        });
    });
}
```

These are just a few cleanups, there may be others.

**Edit:**

Added devnull69's insight to my final updated code. Hopefully it's useful (accept his answer if this was the problem).

**Edit: Other notes**

Why are you doing `$.post` in `chatcom_load_one`? It would make much more sense as a `$.get`, and the query parameters would still be sent. It's not really a problem per se, but it's bad style. This should probably be in a file called `getchat.php` or something instead of doing what I expect is looking for the `text` parameter.

Also, I don't know the implementation of `sendchat2.php`, but you should probably reduce the timeout. Try something like 250ms or so. That's not going to overload the server and it'll improve response time.

Comment: Thanks but still tocom id is not being passed.

Comment: Look at @devnull69's answer. I added it to mine, but accept his if this fixes it.

Comment: @tjameson working fine now but why  send message is slow(it takes about 2-3 seconds to appear into the chat window).Plz  help.

Comment: @tjameson sending is slow. would u plz add $.get or other  approach to your answer.Thanks

Comment: That would require changing your server code, which I don't have access to. Since you're question has been answered, perhaps it's time to open a new question?

Comment: @tjameson yah offcourse.but I have edited my question  with the send function in my server>plz review and edit the answer.you are my only hope now.

Comment: @tjameson  Please review the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550732/faster-approach-for-sending-the-data-to-server-by-ajax-with-the-comaparison-of-p

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previously mentioned problems you invoke the immediately executed function without any parameter. You will have to add the `(id)` parameter to the function call in order to hand over the id element to its local copy inside the function.

```
(function chatcom_load_one(id) {
   ...
}(id));
```